# Date Range Picker Position WRONG

Tags: html, angular, angular-daterangepicker

I am trying to call mat date-range-picker calendar inside a component , that means supposedly i have one component menu, calling component leave from menu component,and in menu component i have mat date range picker calendar.
now the position of calendar,when i call leave component must be after the menu component, as that is how i written in my HTML code. but calendar is showing on top left.
please do help.
I tried adding this to css file. But didnt work for me.

@import '../../../../../../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';

```
         <div class ="calendar">
         <mat-date-range-input [rangePicker]="picker" 
         style="display:none">
         <input matStartDate matInput placeholder="Start date"/>
         <input matEndDate matInput placeholder="End date"/>
          </mat-date-range-input>
           <mat-date-range-picker  #picker  [opened]="true" 
           (closed)="openCalendar(picker)">
             </mat-date-range-picker>
           </div>
```

Comment: Please @Shruti Jain, can you place a piece of code. It's difficult to give some help if you don't share your code...

Comment: HI, I have added the code which i used in leave component , which is inside the menu component . So basically the hierarchy c app->menu->leave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try dropping the `style="display:none"` from `mat-date-range-input` element. It's the only strange thing I see in your code. If it doesn't work you could try to clean your css file and building it again. It could be inheriting the position from another higher level css.

Comment: Thanks , Roberto yes,it solved half of the problem, now my calendar is not scrolling with the page, but it is not at correct position yet.

Comment: Try to drop out the line you added to your css. I mean this one: `@import '../../../../../../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';`

Comment: https://angular-ivy-qfsvyu.stackblitz.io , Please do check @Roberto

Comment: What i want to do is to always open picker but once i click again on leave button, closes the picker. but picker stays open at that time also